# Apache Kafka throws exceptions inside a try block{} catch

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having a problem that I'm not understanding very well, because although I understand the error I'm getting, what I don't understand is why it keeps throwing the exception if I'm supposed to be inside a try{}.

```
try{
    Battle battleDto =  om.readValue(battleObject.toString(), Battle.class);
    try {
        battleDto.setStarPlayer(battleObject.getJSONObject("starPlayer").getString("tag"));
        return battleDto;
    }catch (StreamsException e) {
        log.error("No starPlayer for battleTime: " + battleDto.getBattletime());
        return battleDto;
    }
}catch (JsonProcessingException e ){
    return null;
}
```

The exception occurs when accessing the "StarPlayer" field.
If someone could tell me why it keeps crashing I would appreciate it, as I think there is something very basic that I am not seeing.

```
    Exception in thread "DataTreatment-b3211938-89f1-4cc0-83e8-0e4266286ed5-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=battles, partition=0, offset=0, stacktrace=java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.datatreatment.bsanalyst.controller.dao.entity.BattleDao.getBattleTime()" because "battleDao" is null
at com.datatreatment.bsanalyst.application.service.BattleDaoService.updateDatabase(BattleDaoService.java:26)
at com.datatreatment.bsanalyst.controller.listener.BattleListener.lambda$updateDatabase$0(BattleListener.java:59)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPeek$KStreamPeekProcessor.process(KStreamPeek.java:42)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorAdapter.process(ProcessorAdapter.java:71)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:181)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:181)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:273)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:252)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:219)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:86)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:701)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:701)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1105)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:658)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:564)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:523)

at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:718)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1105)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:658)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:564)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:523)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.datatreatment.bsanalyst.controller.dao.entity.BattleDao.getBattleTime()" because "battleDao" is null
at com.datatreatment.bsanalyst.application.service.BattleDaoService.updateDatabase(BattleDaoService.java:26)
at com.datatreatment.bsanalyst.controller.listener.BattleListener.lambda$updateDatabase$0(BattleListener.java:59)
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Probably the exception is not an instance of `StreamsException` or `JsonProcessingException`. Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: Hi, I just updated the question, so a try{} block only works if the exception that occurs is the one you catch?

Comment: Kind of. It works for the exception in the parameter of the `catch` or any subclasses. In this case the code throws a NullPointerException, which is not a subclass of any of `StreamsException` nor `JsonProcessingException`. I would suggest you also to read a bit about checked and runtime exceptions too, as it might be a bit confusing if you are coming from another language.

Comment: OK, thank you very much! I'll look for some information about what you are saying , greetings